# Can my proposed supervisors for my Masters by dissertation be my referees?

Tags: masters, recommendation-letter

I am applying for grad school, and its the same institution as my undergraduate studies. Can my proposed supervisors write me their recommendation letters as they are the ones that I interacted most closely with?

Comment: If you did work with those professors, I cannot think of any reason they cannot or should not write recommendation letters for you.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously thats the whole point. It is unethical for an academic to write a recommendation letter for a student, he/she didn't interact with. Also, it does not create a problem, if the supervisor is at the same university where you are applying for a master course.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, it is generally quite accepted for a professor to write a recommendation for a student applying to their own program.

The purpose of the recommendation letter is typically not so much to provide "independent" judgement as it is to provide reliable and useful information about an applicant, beyond what can be gleaned from transcripts, publications, and the applicant's own statements.  As such, a professor at the same institution is just as well positioned to provide a recommendation letter as one at another institution.

This can often give students an advantage in applying to their own institution---or a disadvantage if they have picked up a poor reputation. It's not clear to me, however, the degree to which whether there is any ethical issue with that, particularly at the Masters level.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I do not think there would be any ethical issues, but I am afraid that it would be inappropriate..